# numberOfItemsInSection function of collectionview called multiple time only on iOS10

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift3, xcode8

when I converted my project to swift 3 I  am getting this problem , that the method of `numberOfItemsInSection` called multiple time  "like infinite loop"

This problem appears only when the `numberOfItemsInSection` = 0 but if there any items its work normally, Here is my code

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items

    if self.downloadFiles.count == 0 || (downloadFiles[0].modificationDate == nil && downloadFiles[0].fileName == nil)  {
        self.noFilesLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("NoDataToDisplay", comment: "")
        downloadFiles.removeAll()
        self.noFilesLabel.isHidden = false

    } else {

        self.noFilesLabel.isHidden = true
    }

    return self.downloadFiles.count
}
```

Comment: if `self.downloadFiles.count == 0` than why are you  doing `downloadFiles.removeAll()`?

Comment: more check thats it ,

Comment: what if you `return 0`, still happens the same?

Comment: ya ,, the problem was when the return value = 0  , i try to return 0 directly but there is no deferent

Comment: return 0 causes same issue?

Comment: yes its return the same issue

Comment: I think somewhere you are calling table reload repeatedly.

Comment: all self.collectionView.reloadData i comment it and still have the same problem